# Ruby on Rails Youtube Image Embed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, youtube

I'm trying to accomplish this without any plugins.

Basically we just use the standard copy and paste method for embedding Youtube onto our website... the problem, then, is that if we try to share a post of ours with video on facebook... the image thumbnail isn't there.

The thumbnail is always saved in this format:

http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/7Uz1hfza55k/default.jpg

...with the video id coming just before "default.jpg"

I already have three "photo" slots in the database for each post.

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
<%= image_tag("<%= daily.photo .html_safe %>") %>
```

I'm just not sure of the proper syntax so that it gets the photo URL for that particular post.

What I want it to return in the end is something like this:

```
<%= image_tag("http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/7Uz1hfza55k/default.jpg") %>
```

Getting the URL, of course, from the "photo" section of each post's database entry.

For extra credit maybe you could explain a way that I could arrange it so that all the person writing the articles would have to do is enter the video code and it would be automatically inserted in:

```
<%= image_tag("http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/CODEHERE/default.jpg") %>
```

Thank you for your time.

Edit:

Just so we're clear this works:

```
<img src="<%= @daily.photo %>">
```

But this doesn't work:

```
<%= image_tag("<%= daily.photo .html_safe %>") %>
```

They should be the same as far as I know... but they don't work the same. If worse comes to worse I'll just go with img src...

Comment: Can you show the model, where you extract the photo from your database. And also what type is it - a string in DB ?

Comment: Yes. It's a string in the db. And yes the model is shown. <%= image_tag("<%= daily.photo .html_safe %>") %> didn't work. I'm guessing the syntax is a little off.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= image_tag(@daily.photo) %>
```

In ERB, `<%= stuff %>` means: everything inside this is good old plain ruby. There is no need to use the tag twice, as `@daily.photo` is  just an argument for the `image_tag` method.

Comment: So you're saying it's daily_photo and not daily.photo? With no quotes right?